# What is the best method to read a folder sub directory and files in those sub directory?

Tags: php, glob

I have a image folder which contains sub directory for each album of images like

- Images
- Images/Album1
- Images/Album2

in PHP file 
I create a link for each album using a thumbnail for the album using GLOB to read all folders under Images

```
$dir=glob('images/*');
$dir_listing=array();
foreach($dir as $list)  
{
if(is_dir($list))
$dir_listing[]= (basename($list));
}   

$thumbs=glob('images/thumbnails/*');
$count=0;

foreach($thumbs as $th )
{
echo" $dir_listing <br/>"; 
echo"<a href='$dir_listing[$count]' ><img src='$th' /> </a>";
    $count++;
}
```

I use Glob on each page load to get list of directories and images.

- I want to know if there is a better way of doing this.
- I also want to get list of all files and folder based on there Last Modified time in descending Order {*Latest files and Folders first*}.

Is using Glob correct or should we save the sub-directories and files in text file and read from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure if there is a better way of doing this, but your code should definitely work.

Using glob() is the right approach only if you have a relatively low number of files in the directory (<10,000), because if yoy have a lot of files then you could get a "Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted ..." error. In this case, it is best to use opendir();

```
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    // do something with the file
    // note that '.' and '..' is returned even
}
closedir($handle);
```

Finally, use the flag GLOB_NOSORT on glob() so the end result is just like its listed on the directory in case that may be used to give you results based on last modified date.

Hope this helps.